# How should I understand "all the more reason to"?

Tags: meaning

The following sentence is from a [commencement speech](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/answer-sheet/post/romneys-liberty-u-commencement-speech--text/2012/05/14/gIQAaKcPPU_blog.html).

> *All the more reason to* be grateful, this and every day, that we live
>   in America, where the talents God gave us may be used in freedom.

I don't understand the phrase "all the more reason to" even after I looked it up on thefreedictionary.com, which returns the entry:

> **all the more reason for (doing something) and all the more reason to (do something)**
>   with even better reason or cause for doing something. (Can be included in a number of grammatical constructions.)

I don't quite understand the explanation: what does "with even better reason" mean?

Can anybody say something more about this phrase?

Comment: [*With*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/with), [*even*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/even#Adverb), [*better*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/better), [*reason*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reason#Noun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have a reason to visit a nearby town, because you need to buy something for example. Then, you look in the paper and see that your favourite band is playing in that town, on the day you have to visit. Now you have one more reason to visit. It is not only one more reason - it is a better reason.

You could respond to this by saying "Great! X are playing! All the more reason to visit that town!"

Answer (score 0):

It can be used like "one more, even stronger reason", but you'll most frequently find it as counter-argument in a discussion - the opponent offers an argument against your decision, then you turn it around - make the argument work in favor, not against the decision.

> "I'd like to take your car to go to the mall."
>
> "No, it's low on oil. I need to take it to the garage to have the oil changed."
>
> "All the more reason for me to take it, the garage is right next to the mall and they'll do it while I'm doing the shopping."